# Tilde (~) resolving to site root rather than application root in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I have an ASP.Net Web Forms site that I'm trying to add another ASP.Net Web Forms Application to in a subdirectory.  The ASP Application published correctly and runs fine from the subdirectory, however, all links resolve to `http://website.com/destination` rather then `http://website.com/webapp/destination`.

Example:

```
<a id="loginLink" runat="server" href="~/Account/Login.aspx">
```

Resolves to `http://website.com/Account/Login.aspx` instead of `http://website.com/webapp/Account/Login.aspx`.  This is also true of resources such as CSS, scripts and images.

I've looked at a lot of the posts on SO regarding similar issues, but none of them seemed to be the exact same issue I'm having.  A lot of the answers seemed to involve redirecting from code, which would work for links, but I'm not sure how that would resolve the issue with resources.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid doing that for a few different reasons.  Not the least of which is changing every link and resource ref in the app.  But the other issue is how does that work from the master page?  Is ../ relitive to the master template or the page they are on?

Comment: Ok have you converted the virtual directory "webapp" to an application in IIS?

Comment: If not ~/ will resolve to the next available root (in your case your website). And, remember that you could only use ~ with server controls since ASP.Net resolves the actual path at server side.  It'll not work with your CSS and Scripts unless you add a link with runat="server". E.g. <link runat="server" href="~/Css/My.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> Cheers!

Comment: Yep, it's configured as a webapp in IIS, and everything is set to runat server.  That's what prompted this post, I've read everything I can find on the subject, and I can't figure out what the issue is.

Comment: Any updates on that issue?

Answer (score 0):

if use  /  it is from  root path

if use ../  it go to parent path

if use ~/  it is asp.net only support with runat="server" prop. ,it is from app root path.

eg.

```
   <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/abc.aspx" ID="tests">test</asp:HyperLink>
```

is the same as

```
<a href='<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/abc.aspx") %>' >test</a>
```